# Forloop variable and a function combination

Tags: php, for-loop

I was wondering if it's possible to combine a for loop variable and a function together. So it prints out each variable in the loop, I prefer simple solutions please

```
$variable1 = 'hello';
$variable2 = 'goodnight';

for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){
   echo $variable.$x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is called a foreach loop

```
$variables[0] = 'hello';
$variables[1] = 'goodnight';

foreach($variables as $variable){
    echo $variable;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys, this is the solution.

```
${"variable" . $x}
```

hope you guys have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly :

```
function variables($x)
{
    switch($x)
    {
    case 1: return 'hello'; break;
    case 2: return 'good night'; break;
    }
}

for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){
   echo variables($x).'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable1 = 'hello';
$variable2 = 'goodnight';

for($x=1;$x<=2;$x++){
    $test="variable".$x;
    echo $$test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array. Should be simple enough

```
$var = array('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri');

for($x=0; $x<count($var); $x++)
{
    echo $var[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
mon
tue
wed
thu
fri
```